# Configuration NAT/PAT/CGNAT customize rule port 80 to port 80

Tags: apache, router, portforwarding, nat, static-ip-address

I add a static route from port 80 to a localhost port 80 on my router

the website is working from outside my local network (using global IP address)

but when I try to open the global IP address from my local network (same router) it makes a connection timeout

notes

1. I have an Apache web-server running on the host
2. firewall is off both on the router and host
3. if I use the local ip address it works fine

I try telnet it makes a connection and when I use an HTTP GET command it start getting the HTML page then it stops and give me timeout.

any one have any idea.

Comment: I think this is just an unfortunate limitation of your router, not supporting "NAT loopback". It will work on some, not others. Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/is-nat-loopback-on-my-router-a-security-problem

Comment: thank you for your comment, do you have a recommended router that you can share with me.